# adding fill colour to gglot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Aim**: I am trying to add fill colours to my column cart.

**Current attempts**: The method in the cheat sheet shows the function scale_fill_manual(values = c("","","")) or scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens"). Neither option has worked.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
d <- ggplot(dataset3, aes(x = DropoffLocationName, y=Difference)) + geom_col() + theme_test() 
d + scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Purple"))  
d + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")
```

So, any thoughts?

Comment: Your question is not about statistics but about how to use a program often associated with statistics (R, ggplot). The right place to ask this question is stackoverflow. Nevertheless: if you want your plot to vary its aspect depending on the data, then you have to add some aesthetics (eg.: `aes(fill=Location)`, if you have a location column in your data frame). Then the scales you are trying to use are to specify *which* colors to use to fill something. If you just want to change the color in general, then you can add parameters to the `geom` you are using (eg.: `geom_col(color="green")`).

Comment: You haven't mapped fill to a variable by putting `fill = ...` inside `aes()`. Your first line should look something like `ggplot(dataset3, aes(x = DropoffLocationName, y=Difference, fill = Difference))`

Comment: @jkd oops, thank you for that.

Comment: @JanBoyer ahh, that worked. I am not sure why I didn't spot that in the examples.